# Qt file append open mode

Tags: qt

If I want to make a append to a file that may or may not exist...
What is the correct code?

```
if( !file.exists() ){
    mode= QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text;
}else{
    mode= QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text;
}
if( !file_destino.open( mode ) ){
    balblabla...
}
```

Or:

```
if( !file_destino.open( QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text ) ){
    balblabla...
}
```

Or:

```
if( !file_destino.open( QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text ) ){
    balblabla...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text` should be fine either cases if you don't want to truncate it when it exists.